# SCSS if/else bigger than

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

Is it possible to check if size is bigger than or less than is SCSS?
I want to transform this:

```
@function triangle($size, $color, $direction) {
  @if $direction == up {
    //apply rules
  } @else if $direction == right {
    //apply rules
  }
}
```

To this:

```
@function triangle($size, $color, $direction) {
  @if $direction >= up {
    @return ...
  } @else if $direction >= right {
   @return ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sass does support [relational operators](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/relational), but in the case of `$direction >= up` it will return an error. You can't check if something is bigger than up or right. In the case of `$size` you can compare it to other number if it's a number.

```
Error: Undefined operation "9 >= left".
  ╷
2 │   @if $direction >= left {
  │       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
```